# Function to Project xyz to xy Screen Coordinates

Tags: java, c++, 3d, geometry, coordinates

Hi Im trying to create a hybrid 2D/3D game using a commercial 2D game development engine.

The game will have a series of 2D sprites that are displayed on screen based on their depth in a pseudo 3D space not just their x and y position as illustrated.

[image]

If sprite "A" is at point x,y,z (150,20,100) in a world 500 wide, 500 high and 500 deep, where should it be plotted on a 1024x768 res screen?

I cant get my head into the deep theories of 3D screen projection as most solutions here and on the internet do. Just the basics of where the center of a sprite should be on a screen when the sprite is at point xyz.

Can someone assist me with the logic needed, given the scenario in the illustration? Id like a function in any language even pseudo-code that returns the X and Y pair after passing x,y,z parameters to it.

Thanks

Comment: A) Pick a single language. B) I don't quite get the problem here. Can't you just remove the y position? Then it's just a scaling problem

Comment: Did you have a look at "3D Projection" entry of Wikipedia ? Three cases are considered ...

Comment: @jhamon A) Which language are you most proficient in? If you have one you can post your solution using that language.

Comment: @jhamon B) My problem is Im looking for a simple and lean coding mechanism where I can push xyz coordinates into and get xy coordinates back. Most 3D Projection solutions out there seam to be overkill for what I need.

Comment: @Damien I've checked the Wikipedia page thanks I just cant seem to get it at this moment and I dont have the capacity to convert what is described there into a function code I can re-use in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the simplest code and don't want to dive into matrices then try something like this:

```
Vec2 screenCenter = Vec2( screensize.x/2, screensize.y/2 ); // half of your screen resolution
                                                            // try changing it to see what happens
                                                            // you can animate it to add special effects
float perspStrength = 500.0f;   // actually an inverse of perspective strength
                                // lower values means bigger effect

Vec2 project( Vec3 pos )        // projection code
{
    Vec2 localPos = pos - screenCenter; // Move point (0,0) to the center of your screen

    float scale = pos.z/perspStrength;  // scale your Z to ~(0-1) range
    scale += 1.0f;                      // move your Z to ~(1-2) range

    localPos.x /= scale;                // scale position according to Z distance
    localPos.y /= scale;

    Vec2 result = localPos + screenCenter;  // Move point (0,0) back to the corner

    return result;
//    return Vec3( result.x, result.y, scale ); // you can also return scale used for this object
                                                // so you can render distant objects as smaller
}
```

I wrote this code assuming it will be used with float values. I've picked the `500` contant only because you assumed Z to be in range (0,500) so I wanted to move it to (0-1) range. We don't want to have `0`'s in our projection code because we'll be dividing by this value, so we add `1` to move scale to the (1-2) range. Feel free to change those values and see what happens.

**According to your 2nd question:**
I think that you rewrote this code using ints so dividing by 500 cancels your `Z=100` value and it gives the same result as `Z=100` vector. To fix it you can change ints to floats and all should be fine. If you don't want or can't do that and need the code for ints then it needs to be slightly changed:

Instead of floating-point scale we can use `int` and represent scale in 1/1000 units, so the base scale would be 1000.

The simplest way to get a scale:

```
int scale = 1000 - pos.z;
```

If you need scaling of perspective effect you can use this instead:

```
int perspStrength = 100;
int scale = 1000 - (pos.z*perspStrength/100);
```

Now, when you have your `scale` in `1/1000` units you can scale your vectors:

```
localPos.x = localPos.x * scale / 1000;
localPos.y = localPos.y * scale / 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks @kolenda, this i the kind of thing Im looking for and thanks also for including a scale value in the result set but what does float perspStrength = 500.0f; mean? can this value be a bare integer value such as 500?

Comment: I suspect the reason almost all 3D coding solutions get complicated so quickly is because they get into camera and object rotations which I don't need in my scenario. The camera is always looking straight on and the objects are literally flat and rendered as 2D sprites.

Comment: kolenda, after implementing it however I've noticed that in your solution, an object's Z position has no effect on the object's X and Y position.

Your code will display on object at position (100,100,100) in the same screen x,y as an object at position (100,100,0). This shouldn't be the case!